# Add one day to Now() and return as default value in SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-arithmetic

I am attempting to add a day to NOW() and return as the values for a column.
This works

`SELECT NOW() as date`

But this gives an error

`SELECT DATE_ADD( NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) as date`

Is there a way to achieve this in a postgres query?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a [`date_add()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) function in PostgreSQL:

> ```
> ERROR:  function date_add(timestamp with time zone, interval) does not
> exist
> LINE 1: select date_add(now(), interval '1 day');
>                ^
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You
> might need to add explicit type casts.
> ```

but you can use a regular `+` operator to add an `interval` to `timestamptz` that's returned by `now()`. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/1NKWb8DI):

```sql
select now() + '1 day'::interval;
```

You can define that function for convenience:

```sql
create function date_add(arg1 timestamptz, arg2 interval) 
returns timestamptz language sql as $$
select arg1+arg2
$$;

select date_add(now(), interval '1 day') as date;

--             date
---------------------------------
-- 2022-11-29 12:28:12.393508+00
```

But I don't think it's really more convenient than the operator. You'd also have to overload it to make sure how it deals with different types - you can see in the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/1NKWb8DI) how by default PostgreSQL will try to guess and cast automatically.